# Difference between next() and nextElement() in RecursiveIteratorIterator

Tags: php, iterator, spl

What is the difference between `RecursiveIteratorIterator::next()` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator::nextElement()`?

The documentation is slightly less than helpful:

- #### [RecursiveIteratorIterator::next()](http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator.next):

  > RecursiveIteratorIterator::next — Move forward to the next element
- #### [RecursiveIteratorIterator::nextElement()](http://php.net/recursiveiteratoriterator.nextelement):

  > RecursiveIteratorIterator::nextElement — Next element
  >
  > ...
  >
  > Called when the next element is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the PHP source, it appears that `nextElement` is a callback function that can be called "when the next element is available".

```
288  if (object->nextElement && (object->mode == RIT_SELF_FIRST || object->mode == RIT_CHILD_FIRST)) {
289      zend_call_method_with_0_params(&zthis, object->ce, &object->nextElement, "nextelement", NULL);
290  }
```

[Source](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/spl/spl_iterators.c#288).

The default `nextElement` function in the iterator class doesn't appear to do anything at the moment from looking at [spl_iterators.c:801](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/spl/spl_iterators.c#801).

<strike>Right now it looks like a no-op as there is no way to register your own callback for that function and in the PHP source, it currently does nothing.</strike> From looking at the code, if registered, that callback gets called when the iterator moves forward to the next element, prior to acting on the item (e.g. userland code in a foreach loop).

See @RamboCoder's answer for explanation on how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

The *template method* design pattern crops up in some of the spl classes, this is one occurrence. You're expected to extend RecursiveIteratorIterator to provide implementations for the optional hooks, and then the superclass (RecursiveIteratorIterator) will call them at the appropriate times.

```
class A extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
    function nextElement() {
        echo 'hi';
    }

}

$r = new A(new RecursiveArrayIterator([1,2]));
iterator_to_array($r);//hihi
```

You could think of nextElement() as an event handler, except you need to extend the class to provide an implementation of a handler.

Some of the other methods you can hook into are beginChildren() beginIteration() callHasChildren() etc...

Comment: +1 for clearing that up and showing a working example, I updated my answer.  Gives me a whole new view of looking at the PHP source now.  Thanks.